SharePoint "Number" field with number of decimals = Zero. will still show the number with decimals inside the API
I have this Column of type number and number of decimal = Zero:-

now using the SharePoint UI or using Power Apps, if I enter a number with decimals (6.5 for example) seems inside the SharePoint UI the number will get rounded (to 7), as follow:-

but inside Power Apps or SharePoint API (such as GetItems action inside power automate) will still show the original number with decimals (6.5), as follow:-

any advice how this work in sharepoint?
Second question, in general if i change the "number of decimal places" list inside the column type, from Zero to Automatic will this cause any data lose? i do not think so? Now, if i do so at least the SharePoint UI will be compatible with the API, Power Apps and Power Automate.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Purpose of setting Number of decimal places is for UI displaying and not validation. Unfortunately Microsoft has not explicitly stated that in field settings.
You can even set Number of decimal places : 0, open build-in form, enter 33.12345 in field and it will save without any error. That value will be actually saved in item properties - but displayed as 33.
Value 33.12345 will be retrieved via Power Automate actions, REST API, etc.
Yes, you can change field setting "Number of decimal places" value without data loss.
